# HTML anchor link - href with confirm dialog

Tags: javascript, html, anchor

I want use confirm dialog for anchor tag. So I did below code:

```
<a href="javascript:a=2;if(confirm('sdsd'))__doPostBack('id','START');"> click </a>
```

I have used pseudo protocol to display confirm dialog. If I use single line with doPostBack like below:

```
<a href="javascript:if(confirm('sdsd'))__doPostBack('id','START');"> click </a>
```

it's working fine. If I use another line then confirm dialog cancel is working weird. I want use inline script. Is it possible to use multiple line in pseudo protocol?

Comment: You silly devs with your inline anchor JS shenanigans

Comment: "I swear to God, I'll pistol whip the next guy who says "shenanigans"!

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the JavaScript in your ugly `href` attribute in a self executing function.

```
<a href="javascript:(function(){
    a=2;
    if(confirm('sdsd'))__doPostBack('id','START');
})()"> click </a>
```

But a better solution would be:

```
<a href="#" onclick="(function(){
    a=2;
    if(confirm('sdsd'))__doPostBack('id','START');
})(); return false;"> click </a>
```

Comment: Why are you binding a self-executing anonymous function to a click event? The value of `onclick` should be a callback function. It will execute on click, that't the point.

Comment: @AlienWebguy I found that multiline anonymous functions don't work but a self executing function allows for multiline silliness that the OP asked for.